# I can't add new entry

Tags: openldap

I try to add new entry to ldap and i have no idea why it does not work.

I have `addPeople.ldif` file:

```
dn: ou=People,dc=example,dc=com,dc=au
ou: people
description: All people in organisation
objectClass: organizationalUnit
```

I enter following command:

```
ldapadd -x -D "cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com,dc=au" -w secret -f ~/addPeople.ldif
```

Result:

```
adding new entry "ou=People,dc=example,dc=com,dc=au"
ldap_add: No such object (32)
```

Accordance with quickstart openldap documentation command:

```
ldapsearch -x -b '' -s base '(objectclass=*)' namingContexts
```

returns:

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <> with scope baseObject
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: namingContexts 
#

#
dn:
namingContexts: dc=example,dc=com,dc=au

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

How to solve this issue?

EDIT

May be there is no `dc=example,dc=com,dc=au` entry.

```
$ ldapsearch -b 'dc=example,dc=com,dc=au' -s base '(objectclass=*)'
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=example,dc=com,dc=au> with scope baseObject
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 32 No such object

# numResponses: 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution in this [faq](http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/182.html). 
At the beginning I should add initial entry. I created `firstelement.ldif`:

```
dn: dc=example,dc=com,dc=au
o: My Company
objectclass: organization
objectclass: dcObject

dn: cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com,dc=au
cn: Manager
sn: Manager
objectclass: person
```

I executed following command:

```
ldapadd -D "cn=Manager, dc=example,dc=com,dc=au" -W -f ~/firstelement.ldif
```

Earlier I also added an initial entry, but as it turned out I was doing it wrong. My first and wrong ldif file with initial entry:

```
version:1
# This DN is first to be loaded into database, then first level DN, then 2nd level, etc.
dn :dc=example,dc=com,dc=au     # DN
objectClass: dcObject           # required because 'dc' is packaged here; is AUXILLARY
objectClass: organization     # STRUCTURAL needed because 'dcObject' is AUXILLARY
dc: example                            # 'dc' is MUST as defined in 'dcObject'
o: example                              # 'o' is MUST as defined in 'organization'
description:Example Company  # 'description' is MA
```